# child div not inheriting parent curve border

Tags: css

I have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/6/

How do I get the logo portion to be curved also without specifying? Seems this should be possible. Here is the code...

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:200px;
    min-height: 985px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px -7px #333, -10px 0px 10px -7px #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}


.logo {
    position: static;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,102,0.7);
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.logo {
    ....
    border-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45jQm/11/

Comment: That works for the top, but inherit also makes the bottom curved. For the logo, I just want the top curved.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the overflow:hidden to the parent div should hide the corners from any child div. No need to add any css to the child div (like the logo in your example).

```
.parent {
    …
    border-radius: 5px %* or whatever you choose *%
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

an example: https://jsfiddle.net/uxrzgojh/

*This answer is for the future explorers!*